# In a boot to VHD setup, is it possible to get the filename of the VHD?

Tags: vhd, boot-to-vhd

I have a physical computer that I have two BCD entries for VHDs to boot from.  I am looking for a way to programmatically get the name of the current VHD that has been booted to.  I see possible solutions when using Hyper-V, but I'm booting on a physical machine in this scenario. I have seen the same behavior set on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

The output of BCDEDIT and WMI (BCDSTORE class) do not show the filename for the booted VHD (the second entry is for the second VHD, the third entry is for the current boot):

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=D:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {4c6d3c84-4bb6-11e3-bc07-b5a095a1a2a8}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
                        {4c6d3c81-4bb6-11e3-bc07-b5a095a1a2a8}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  vhd=[D:]\VHD\v2.vhd
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows Embedded Standard
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                vhd=[D:]\VHD\v2.vhd
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {4c6d3c84-4bb6-11e3-bc07-b5a095a1a2a8}
nx                      OptIn
detecthal               Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {4c6d3c82-4bb6-11e3-bc07-b5a095a1a2a8}
nx                      OptIn
bootstatuspolicy        IgnoreAllFailures
```

I realize I could specify the filename in the description, but for the final application, I need to use them to label them for the end-user.

Comment: Are the VHDs different in any big way, or just a few minor tweaks?

Comment: One is highly customized, and one isn't.  I simplified my use case quite a bit, but it is a requirement for this project to be able to boot to the second VHD and "fix" things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcdedit /v will provide the full path for the currently booted VHD.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it just shows me the BCD information - `/v Command-line option that displays entry identifiers in full, rather than using names for well-known identifiers. Use /v by itself as a command to display entry identifiers in full for the ACTIVE type.`

Comment: bcdedit /v does show me the information I'm looking for, but not which entry was booted from.  I can get that information from a plain "bcdedit", however and match the "resumeobject" GUID.  Still looking for a way to do it in PowerShell or C#, but I'll parse the text output if needed.

Comment: I can't figure it out in PowerShell, I think /V makes it parse the store file and gather information not in WMI.